# Forge Viewer: Materials doesn't display correctly from .rvt

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have added some materials to a couple of the rooms in my Revit model which seems to end up displaying pure green color (no "Office" text) when the file is uploaded to the Forge Viewer. Is this a familiar matter?

Here are the images for reference:

[Revit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHBXL.png)

[Forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ybxA.png)

Kind regards,

Comment: As far as I know, the texture that uses customized file is not supported during Forge translation, only the Revit built in material/texture are supported. That's the reason why you get the default green color. Our Revit/Forge expert may confirm you with more information.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is actually a custom material imported from FormIt. Do you know whether there is any workaround to get custom materials work in a rvt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Zhong Wu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6510138/zhong-wu), as of now (Jan/2018) this is not supported: the translation will not understand materials from custom images.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was reviewing dasher360.com, which is a detailed building with materials and textures. Kindly correct me, but my understanding is that a zipped OBJ/MTL/PNG is the only file-combination that generates custom materials and textures (?). Do you know what program and what filetype that was used for the dasher project?